# Ingress on GKE is using ephemeral addresses despite specifiying a static one

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

This is my ingress configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: public-ingress
  namespace: platform
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "app-staging-ip"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: app-central
    servicePort: 8080
```

However, what I always end up seeing on the panel is that it uses an Ephemeral address.

This is the output of `gcloud compute addresses list`

```
NAME                          REGION       ADDRESS         STATUS
app-staging-ip                asia-south1  35.200.149.62   RESERVED
```

I have no idea why the ingress is still picking up an ephemeral id and not the one I have reserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your IP is regional. Needs to be global. Create it with:

```
gcloud compute addresses create app-staging-ip --global
```